# Open port 8082 on ubuntu for remote access

Tags: iptables, firewall

I need to open port 8082 on my linux box for remote access. I can access the application on port 8082 locally, but not from my other box.

Ports 8080 and 8081 are accessible locally as well as remote. 8080 and 8081 have applications attached that were installed via apt-get, whereas 8082 has a program running from eclipse (own development).

I have seen [How to open a 8080 port for an application, with iptables](https://serverfault.com/q/248568) and others like that and followed the instructions, but still could not access 8082 remotely.

One interesting point is that, when doing

```
sudo iptables -L  --line-numbers
```

I only see my entries for port 8082, **and nothing else**!
Meanwhile I deleted those entries, too.

```
ufw status
```

gives "inactive".

This looks to me as if the old goods of firewalls and crossroads now have new names by which they must be summoned.

Question is, is there really a new set of commands for handling routing and firewall, if yes, how are they used, if no, why are the old commands not working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your application is most likely listening only to the localhost network interface, that is `127.0.0.1:8082`, therefore it can be reached only from localhost.

You can check this by running `netstat -lnp`, and checking the Local address column corresponding to your software. If it is `127.0.0.1:8082`, this is the reason and you need to change your software to listen to `0.0.0.0:8082` or `:::8082`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works now. Still I'm unclear why I don't need to open the port? I can't believe there is no firewall by default?!?

Comment: Usually even if the firewall is included in the installation, its default policy is to allow everything, because the sysadmin is supposed to configure the firewall according to his needs.