# How to make sure 8080 is accessbile outside the server?

Tags: iptables, http, port

[How to open a 8080 port for an application, with iptables](https://serverfault.com/questions/248568/how-to-open-a-8080-port-for-an-application-with-iptables)

I see the above thread. And I run the following commands. But it seems that 8080 is still accessible outside the machine. Does anybody know what is wrong?

```
$ netstat -tanpu | grep ":8080"
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 165.91.211.165:8080     0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      26098/python3   

$ sudo iptables -I INPUT 1 -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT

$ sudo iptables -nvL
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 5039 packets, 935K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8080
    0     0 REJECT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:25 reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80 reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       127.0.0.1            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5900
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       127.0.0.1            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5901
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       127.0.0.1            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5902
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       127.0.0.1            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5903
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       127.0.0.1            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5904
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       127.0.0.1            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5905
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       127.0.0.1            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5906
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       127.0.0.1            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5907
    0     0 REJECT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5900 reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5901 reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5902 reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5903 reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5904 reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5905 reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5906 reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5907 reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:143 reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:993 reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

Comment: Incoming traffic from off campus to your IP address
 appears to be blocked. [Contact IT](http://it.tamu.edu/Contact_Us.php) for further information.

Comment: I am the administrator of the server. How can you tell what is blocked? How to unblock it? BTW, the client and the server are in the same network.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying access this URI outside your  corporate/university, or your computer is in the same network that your server? If you are trying access from outside, I believe that there is a firewall between your “browser” and your server.

Another point is that you define the IP address on web server config (not 0.0.0.0). Check if your IP address match with this address, and if you are accessing by FQDN (server.corp.com) if this name resolve the correct IP address.

Comment: My computer and the server are in the same network.

Comment: What address are you using to access on browser?

Comment: It is 165.91.211.165

Comment: Can you try to bind 0.0.0.0 address instead this IP address?